# I can't use variables in a long title in Matplotlib if I split it to fit the PEP8 length

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, string-formatting

I'm trying to use a title with variables to show some data which indicates some parameters used for generating the plot, and the date and hour to know when it was generated.

The problem is it only works if the title is written in one line (too long for appropriate coding).

When I tried to split it the program stopped inserting the value as you can see in the example.

The only way it worked right is:

```
plt.title(f'Fitted 4th-degree Polynomial Curve of {window_2} years, Column {j}, Window {window}, Fecha {hoy} {now}', size=16, weight='bold')
```

[image: Desired result]

I tried all the possible solutions to split the title I knew and I've found on the internet, but none of them works, because when I split the title text it only appears the name of the variables, not their values, after the line break.

```
plt.title(f'Fitted 4th-degree Polynomial Curve of {window_2} years'\
              ' Column {j}, Window {window} \nFecha: {hoy} {now}', size=16, weight='bold')
```

```
plt.title(f'Fitted 4th-degree Polynomial Curve of {window_2} years'
              +' Column {j}, Window {window} \nFecha: {hoy} {now}', size=16, weight='bold')
```

```
plt.title(f'Fitted 4th-degree Polynomial Curve of {window_2} years', size=16, weight='bold')
plt.title('Column {j}, Window {window} \nFecha: {hoy} {now}', size=16, weight='bold')
```

Each of them returns the same error (more or less)

[image: Erroneous graphic's title]

Comment: To post a multi-line code block, put triple backticks on the lines before and after the code.

Comment: Or mark the code with the mouse and click on the `{}` tool.

Comment: If you're splitting an f-string, you have to put `f` before each part: `f'foo' f'{bar}'`

Comment: To further clarify what @Barmar is saying, each new quotation is it's own string which needs to be set as an f-string.

Comment: I reformatted the question to fit your requirements. I didn't know how to post it properly, but I think right now is well.

Comment: Thank you @jared !!!
The following code from that answer works just great:
```
plt.title(f'Fitted 4th-degree Polynomial Curve of {window_2} years,'
              f' Column {j}, Window {window}, \nFecha {hoy} {now}', 
              size=16, weight='bold')
```
But I don't know how to post the image in this comment...

Comment: You don't need to post any follow-up images. If the duplicate link I shared answers the question then you can close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @jared !!!

The following code from that answer works just great:

```
plt.title(f'Fitted 4th-degree Polynomial Curve of {window_2} years,'
          f' Column {j}, Window {window}, \nFecha {hoy} {now}', 
              size=16, weight='bold')
```

[image]